# Stop intent for Actions on google

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to create a custom stop intent. It seems like the case when i test it on google home. Google assistant takes over and my intent is not called. Can we fix this? or override Stop keyword for assistant while we are in our action?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways a user can always exit an action. "Stop" is one, and there are several others. These are global, so you can't prevent it from happening. What you can do is override the response and add a short good-bye message.

See the documentation on conversation exits: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits